# How does Bdieved and lichatchilah work?

Tags: halacha

I've been confused for a while now. When somethings "mutur bidieved" but lichatchilah do blank, does that mean if you have no choice or accidently did  X then it's fine? Or is it that it's just "better/recommended" to do the lichatchilah? Does it vary?

Comment: I think we have a question elsewhere on this site already. Bli neder I'll track it down and link it here.

Comment: @ezra maybe you were thinking of this? https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10217/11501 - I even think it is a dupe?